# cron to delete after executing

Tags: cron

I have a `cron` job which unzips a file and executes it. The `cron` is set to unzip, execute and delete the .zip file after. It's executing fine but it's not deleting the file. Here's the `cron`:

```
/usr/bin/wget -q -nd --delete-after 'url of plugin to execute the file'
```

I tried to add a second `cron` which would delete the files that are older than 15 days from the folder but this seems to "bother" the first `cron` to execute properly.

The second `cron` I used was:

```
/usr/bin/find /directory/ -mtime +15 -exec /bin/rm {} \; > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Post your entire first cron script.  There is nothing in your `wget` line that actually executes anything.  `--delete-after` is really not indented for what you are trying to use it for - see the [man](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) page.

Comment: the entire line is : /usr/bin/wget -q -nd --delete-after 'URL/index.php?option=com_fwrealestate&task=processPlugin&plugin=importmls'

Comment: You definitely want to check a question of mine. It has an answer by Stephane Chazelas that explains how you can create an interactive shell that is identical to the environment your cron job will see. If you walk through his little procedure, you get a prompt and you can test your cronjob step by step and see where it fails. unix.stackexchange.com/a/56503/16841 Sure it isn't a 100% match for your question, but it can help you troubleshoot crontab issues.

Comment: Read the `wget` man page and study the meaning of `--delete-after`. It deletes all downloaded files *immediately* after downloading them; it doesn't give you a chance to do anything with them. (It's useful for pre-fetching pages through a proxy.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# 

/usr/bin/wget -q -nd --delete-after 'url of plugin to execute the file'
if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
  /usr/bin/find /directory/ -mtime +15 -exec /bin/rm {} \; > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

feel free to modify it for your needs

Comment: should I put this in cron?

Comment: copy and paste that into a file, chmod 755 it and _THEN_ put it into a cron

Comment: It seems like it's working. Thanks! However, I also have setup to receive an email every time the wget cron runs but I am not receiving it. Would you know why?

Comment: check your logs, you'll find your answer there